# Got GATEWAY_TIMEOUT when use "sbt intellij” under scala source flolder

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have download scala source code, as the readme said, I can use IntelliJ to the compiler the code.

the README.md under /src/IntelliJ tell me to run "sbt IntelliJ" first

I run this command many times, got an error:

```
[error] Could not determine commit date + SHA: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: One of setGitDir or setWorkTree must be called.

[error] SERVER ERROR: GATEWAY_TIMEOUT url=https://repo.lightbend.com/typesafe/scala-sha-bootstrap/org/scala-lang/bootstrap/02fe2ed93766323a13f22c7a7e2ecdcd84259b6c/test/files/lib/annotations.jar

[error] SERVER ERROR: GATEWAY_TIMEOUT url=https://repo.lightbend.com/typesafe/scala-sha-bootstrap/org/scala-lang/bootstrap/b1ec8a095cec4902b3609d74d274c04365c59c04/test/files/lib/genericNest.jar

[error] SERVER ERROR: GATEWAY_TIMEOUT url=https://repo.lightbend.com/typesafe/scala-sha-bootstrap/org/scala-lang/bootstrap/3794ec22d9b27f2b179bd34e9b46db771b934ec3/test/files/lib/macro210.jar

[error] SERVER ERROR: GATEWAY_TIMEOUT url=https://repo.lightbend.com/typesafe/scala-sha-bootstrap/org/scala-lang/bootstrap/cd33e0a0ea249eb42363a2f8ba531186345ff68c/test/files/lib/nest.jar

[error] SERVER ERROR: GATEWAY_TIMEOUT url=https://repo.lightbend.com/typesafe/scala-sha-bootstrap/org/scala-lang/bootstrap/1b11ac773055c1e942c6b5eb4aabdf02292a7194/test/files/speclib/instrumented.jar
```

[error] SERVER ERROR: GATEWAY_TIMEOUT [url](https://repo.lightbend.com/typesafe/scala-sha-bootstrap/org/scala-lang/bootstrap/02fe2ed93766323a13f22c7a7e2ecdcd84259b6c/test/files/lib/annotations.jar)

all the file need to download from repo.lightbend.com failed

how to fix it?

Comment: Do you use firewall or proxy in your network?

Comment: I think the network is not the problem